# One or more of these issues are policy violations. You must fix these issues. Admob?

Tags: android, admob, ads

Admob keeps saying This is a policy violation. You must fix this issue!

App status: Restricted Demand,
Must Fix: Yes,
Issue: Encouraging Clicks

I update my App many times I requested for review but Admob does not approve.
I get emails by saying;

Here are some details

Please be aware that because your app was found to be in violation of our program policies, ads to your app may be restricted or disabled. If you have modified your app to be in compliance with our policies or you feel this violation is in error, please visit the AdMob Policy Center to view this violation and request another review. Your account remains active, and you are welcome to place Google ads on apps that comply with AdMob Publisher Guidelines and Policies. To help prevent policy violations in the future, we recommend reviewing these references to help keep your account in good standing. Please visit the AdMob Policy Center to view any pending violations.

I remove ads from the main activity and also do not show many ads on my app. I am really tired of keeping appealing and Admob keeps rejecting without telling me the clear issue.

Anyone, please help me what should I do.
Thanks